# Wrapping events with TaskCompletionSource vs. BufferBlock<T>

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow, taskcompletionsource

There's a pattern discussed by Lucian here ( [Tip 3: Wrap events up in Task-returning APIs and await them](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Lucian03-TipsForAsyncThreadsAndDatabinding) ).

I am trying to implement it on a frequently called method that looks something like the contrived code below:

```
public Task BlackBoxAsync() 
{ 
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Object>();  // new'ed up every call
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            DoSomethingStuff(); 
            tcs.SetResult(null); 
        } 
        catch(Exception exc) { tcs.SetException(exc); } 
    }); 
    return tcs.Task; 
}
```

I am worried about the performance, when `TaskCompletionSource` is being new'ed up every call (let's just say I call this method every 100 ms).

I was then thinking of using `BufferBlock<T>` instead, thinking that it won't be new'ed up every call. So it would look like:

```
private readonly BufferBlock<object> signalDone; // dummy class-level variable, new'ed up once in CTOR

public Task BlackBoxAsync() 
{ 

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            DoSomethingStuff(); 
            signalDone.Post(null);
        } 
        catch(Exception exc) {  } 
    }); 
    return signalDone.ReceiveAsync(); 
}
```

The calling objects would call it like:

```
for (var i=0; i<10000; i++) {
 await BlackBoxAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Does anybody have any thoughts about using `BufferBlock<T>` instead?

Comment: Are you aware of reactive extensions?

Comment: Is this"new" and better than TAP?

Comment: [Rx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) is older than TAP but [it was updated to use TAP](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Bart-De-Smet-Rx-Updat-NET-45-Async-WinRT) when 4.5 came out. It is a framework, not a separate system (Kind of like Entity Framework vs `SqlCommand`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No matter what solution you'll go with, if you want to `await` a task every time you call this method, creating a new `Task` is inevitable because tasks aren't reusable. The simplest way to do that is by using `TaskCompletionSource`.

So The first option is preferable IMO to using a `BufferBlock` (which, unsurprisingly, [creates a new `TaskCompletionSource` on `ReceiveAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/819f3c3c151a716cf59c0d2f185f4f6ceb8d49fd/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Base/DataflowBlock.cs#L1155))

---

More to the point, your code seems to simply offload work to the `ThreadPool` and return a task representing that work. Why aren't you using a simple `Task.Run`?

```
public Task BlackBoxAsync() 
{
    return Task.Run(() => DoSomethingStuff());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. The method is a contrived one, just to illustrate the scenario. My real use is actually an event wrapped by a TaskCompletionSource.

Comment: @alpinescrambler Got it. So disregard the second part.